# make services request permission to open ports?

Tags: permissions, security

Is there a way to make services request permission to open ports? Basically to start up with all ports closed, as root so services will have to request permission to open them?, and you can decide to allow or deny the port to open. I’ve done an port scan with zenmap and there are several ports that are unnecessary open, and I don’t know what is coming in and leaving the system, especially form port 443, which is going to TOR so wireshark doesn’t really help. (12.04)

Answer (score 0):

To prevent ports from opening, you should stop the services opening them (or disable their automatic startup). Then, you will be able to start or stop them manually using the `service` command.

Of course, it's possible to block ports with a firewall, but this will run useless services and create errors.

BTW, the port 443 is allocated to `bacula` (a distributed backup program) according to `/etc/services`. You can take a look at it to discover which services use which ports.

HTH